# How to get TypeScript intellisense in WebStorm on Aangular-cli 3rd party libraries?

Tags: angular, typescript, webstorm, angular-cli

I have a working Angular2 app created using the angular-cli quickstart instructions. I've added a 3rd party library with typings. The code is running fine, but WebStorm does not provide intellisense for the typings. WebStorm is configured to use tsconfig; However, Angular 2 is not using this. My typings are at:

```
node_modules/@types/createjs/index.d.ts
node_modules/@types/createjs-lib/index.d.ts
```

How do I get WebStorm to use all, or a subset of, the typings in node_modules/@types for intellisense?

If it helps, following are the cli commands that added the library and typings.

```
npm install createjs-collection --save
npm install @types/createjs --save-dev
npm install @types/createjs-lib --save-dev
```

Comment: webstorm 2016.2 supports /@types, so this must be a configuration issue. I'd suggest creating a support ticket

Comment: Did you include your typings in tsconfig.json? `"types": ["createjs "]` for example..

Comment: @lena, thanks for the heads up. I installed 2016.2.3 and intellisense is now working.

Comment: @KrisHollenbeck, no I hadn't. I was hoping it would work in Webstorm without using the tsconfig like I had prior to using the angular-cli. See, my comment to Iena, it is now working with 2016.2.3. I'm sure adding them to tsconfig would have worked, so maybe for those stuck on 2016.1.